# How does file system permission behave on different systems sharing an NFS export?

Tags: permissions, users, nfs

I'm familiar with how Linux permissions work on a single machine, but what happens when a directory is shared (specifically via NFS)?

Also, what happens when two users are seemingly the same (same name, UID etc), and is there some way of convincing NFS that two users on different systems are actually the same and should have identical privileges?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use NFSv3 to map on user and group IDs. If you don't want to map on IDs use NFSv4 instead which maps on user- and groupnames.

So if you have two different clients who have a user called `user-host-a` and `user-host-b` who both have UID 500 they both have access to the files when NFSv3 is used.

When you have two different clients who have a user called `myuser` with different IDs, 500 on host-a, 501 on host-b, the user will have access on the NFS files when NFSv4 is used.

In short, no you can not convince NFS that two different users are actually the same other than by keeping the IDs or names the same.

Another approach might be to use NFSv4 and use ACLs to grant access to both user accounts. On NFSv3 you can create a common group for both accounts and change the group ID on the files on the NFS server.